# Rendering and updating a Symfony form with related records?

Tags: symfony1, propel, symfony-forms

I have two tables. I'm rendering fields of two tables (`user` and `user_education`). One user can have multiple records (educations details). To edit an user's information, I'm able to retrieve only one record of particular `user_education`'s details . How do I retrieve multiple records of the `user_education` table for a particular user? I'm rendering fields from both tables in single page called `editSuccess()`.

I've created object of both forms, as shown below

```
foreach ($user->getUserEducations() as $edu)
{
     $education =  $edu;
     break;
}


$this->form = new stFormProfile($user);
$this->form1 = new UserEducationForm($education);
```

In above code `$education` is a single record of `user_education`. I should pass an array of `user_education` objects ( `$user->getUserEducations()` ). But it won't accept a array of objects.

I'm binding values as shown below,

```
$this->form1->bind($request->getParameter('user_education'),
$request->getFiles('user_education'));
$this->form->bind($request->getParameter('profile'), $request->getFiles('profile'));
```

I'm saving the updated values using the below code,

```
$this->form->save();
$this->form1->save();
```

User table's fields are getting updated. But not for `user_education` table. I'm getting 
**`_csrf_token` [Required.]** error.

And `UserEducationForm.class.php` is created by Symfony itself using the database schema which I had given initially . In that schema I didn't specify any primary keys for the `user_education` table. So Symfony itself created a column called `id` with the primary key. Is this affecting anything?

I'm rendering those fields as below

```
print $form["username"]->renderLabel()
print $form["username"]->render() 
print $form["email"]->renderLabel() 
print $form["email"]->render() 
print $form["firstname"]->renderLabel() 
print $form["firstname"]->render() 
print $form["lastname"]->renderLabel() 
print $form["lastname"]->render() 
print $form['skillset']->renderLabel() 
print $form['skillset']->render() 
print $form['years_of_experience']->renderLabel() 
print $form['years_of_experience']->render()
```

## Education Details

```
print $form1['college_name']->renderLabel() 
print $form1['college_name']->render() 
print $form1['coursename']->renderLabel() 
print $form1['coursename']->render() 
print $form1['percentage']->renderLabel()
```

I need to render multiple rows of Education details table (using foreach).

Comment: Can you show the code you have in the template to render the form that is generating the _csrf_token [Required.] error. Its likely the field is not being added to the form

Comment: Is this still with Symfony 1.0.16, like your other questions? In newer versions of Symfony you solve this with [*embedded forms*](http://propel.posterous.com/embed-relation-forms-in-one-line-with-sfprope), which do exactly what you need. If you want to emulate this behavior in this (very) old version of Symfony I think you'll have to do some heavy lifting yourself. (Use `@Jan` when you reply in a comment and I get a notification)

Comment: @d.syph.3r: Thanks, I updated the template render code .

Comment: @Jan:Thanks, Actually We are extending an old project which is built on Symfony 1.1.6.

Comment: Symfony 1.1 already has support for embedding forms, but automatically saving the values was [added in Symfony 1.2](http://www.symfony-project.org/tutorial/1_2/en/whats-new#chapter_3fb3b0c857177a2b6740a5dcbc0fb8c7_sub_nested_forms). I recommend you look into embedded forms, they prevent name clashes and give you other benefits. You can still emulate the saving of related objects in your own form code.

Answer (score 1):

You need to render the _csrf_token field aswell

```
print $form['_csrf_token'] 

print $form1['_csrf_token']
```

Comment: Or remove it from the widget and validation schemes. It is added in [`sfForm::addCSRFProtection`](http://trac.symfony-project.org/browser/tags/RELEASE_1_1_6/lib/form/sfForm.class.php#L578).

Comment: @Jan. Removing a security feature such as CSRF protection is surely a bad thing?

Comment: Indeed, my mistake: you should only remove CSRF fields for the *extra* forms, and keep one for the main form. [The `sfForm::embedForm` function](http://trac.symfony-project.org/browser/tags/RELEASE_1_1_6/lib/form/sfForm.class.php#L258) does that too.